Covariant (absolute) derivative of a vector along a curve -- compare cartesian vs. polar coordinates
BACKGROUND: Suppose $A^μ$ is a vector field and $x^μ(λ)$ is a curve in spacetime. A first guess at measuring the change in $A^μ$ along the curve might be
$$\frac{dA^μ(x(λ))}{dλ} = \frac{∂A^μ}{∂x^ν} \frac{dx^ν(λ)}{dλ} = A^μ_{\,\,\,,ν}\,u^ν.$$
This is not a good definition for two reasons. First, $dA^μ/dλ$ defined in this way is not a vector, since $A^μ_{\,\,\,,ν}$ is not a tensor. Second, $dA^μ/dλ$ depends on both the change in $A$ from point to point as well as the choice of coordinates which determine the components $A^μ$.
EXAMPLE: For example (in flat space $R^2$) let $B$ be the constant vector $B(x,y)=α\hat{\bf{x}} + β\hat{\bf{y}}$ where $\hat{\bf{x}}$ and $\hat{\bf{y}}$ are the unit vectors in Cartesian coordinates. Then clearly
$$\frac{dB^μ}{dλ} = \frac{∂B^μ}{∂x}\frac{dx}{dλ} + \frac{∂B^μ}{∂y}\frac{dy}{dλ} = 0.$$
However, changing to polar coordinates $(r,θ)$ and using
$$ \begin{align*}
\hat{\bf{x}} = \cos⁡θ\,\hat{\bf{r}} - \sin⁡θ\,\hat{\bf{θ}} \\
\hat{\bf{y}} = \sin⁡θ\,\hat{\bf{r}} + \cos⁡θ\,\hat{\bf{θ}}
\end{align*}$$
we have $$B(r,θ) = (α\cos⁡θ + β\sin⁡θ)\hat{\bf{r}} + (β\cos⁡θ - α\sin⁡θ)\hat{\bf{θ}}.$$
Therefore, calculating $dB/dλ$:
$$\frac{dB^r}{dλ} = \frac{∂B^r}{∂r} \frac{dr}{dλ} + \frac{∂B^r}{∂θ}\frac{dθ}{dλ} = (-α\sin⁡θ + β\cos⁡θ)\frac{dθ}{dλ}$$
$$\frac{dB^θ}{dλ} = \frac{∂B^θ}{∂r} \frac{dr}{dλ} + \frac{∂B^θ}{∂θ}\frac{dθ}{dλ} = (-α\cos⁡θ - β\sin⁡θ)\frac{dθ}{dλ}$$
Hence, $dB^μ/dλ \neq 0$ even though $B$ is a constant vector.
The better measurement of the change in $A^μ$ along the curve is the covariant derivative of $A^μ$ along the curve
$$\frac{DA^μ(x(λ)}{Dλ} ≡ A^μ_{\,\,\,;ν} \,u^ν = \left( A^μ_{\,\,\,,ν} + Γ^μ_{νσ} A^σ \right) u^ν = \frac{dA^μ}{dλ} + Γ^μ_{νσ} A^σ u^ν .$$
This is plainly a vector.
PROBLEM: Notice that in the previous example involving a constant vector $B$:
$$ \begin{align*}
\frac{DB^r}{Dλ} &= \frac{dB^r}{dλ} + Γ^r_{νσ} B^σ u^ν \\
&= (-α\sin⁡θ + β\cos⁡θ)  \frac{dθ}{dλ} + Γ^r_{θθ} B^θ  \frac{dθ}{dλ} \\
&= (-α\sin⁡θ + β\cos⁡θ) \frac{dθ}{dλ} - r(β\cos⁡θ - α\sin⁡θ) \frac{dθ}{dλ}
\end{align*}$$
I was hoping for this to $=0$, but you see how the $r$ coming from $Γ^r_{θθ}=-r$ spoils it.
The $\theta$ equation is even worse:
$$ \begin{align*}
\frac{DB^θ}{Dλ}
&= \frac{dB^θ}{dλ} + Γ^θ_{νσ} B^σ u^ν \\
&= (-α\cos⁡θ - β\sin⁡θ)\frac{dθ}{dλ} + r^{-1}(β\cos⁡θ - α\sin⁡θ)\frac{dr}{dλ} + r^{-1}(α\cos⁡θ + β\sin⁡θ)  \frac{dθ}{dλ}.
\end{align*}$$
This doesn't look like zero at all!
In these equations I have used the Christoffel symbols for plane polar coordinates $Γ_{θθ}^r = -r$ and $Γ_{rθ}^θ = r^{-1}$.
Something's gone wrong. Obviously, if $DB^\mu/Dλ=0$ in cartesian coordinates, then it must vanish in polar coordinates as well, since this is a vector equation.
What's gone wrong here?

I think this is just a normalization issue. Let $\mathbf{x} = (r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$ then we have $$\partial_r = \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} \partial_x + \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\partial_y = \cos\theta\partial_x + \sin\theta\partial_y$$ which is precisely your $\mathbf{e}_r$. However, the natural basis vector for $\theta$ is actually $$\partial_\theta = \frac{\partial x}{\partial\theta}\partial_x + \frac{\partial y}{\partial\theta}\partial_y = -r\sin\theta\partial_x + r\cos\theta\partial_y = r\begin{pmatrix}-\sin\theta \\ \cos\theta\end{pmatrix} = r \mathbf{e}_\theta$$
With these conventions you get the right Christoffel symbols, i.e. from the metric $g = \mathrm{diag}(1, r^2)$, where the $r^2$ appears since $|r\mathbf{e}_\theta|^2 = r^2$. Your vector is then
$$B = (\alpha \cos\theta + \beta \sin\theta) \mathbf{e}_r + (-\alpha\sin\theta + \beta \cos\theta)\mathbf{e}_\theta = (\alpha\cos\theta + \beta\sin\theta) \partial_r + \frac{-\alpha\sin\theta + \beta\cos\theta}{r} \partial_\theta$$
which cancels with the $r$ from the Christoffel symbol. I haven't looked at $\mathrm{D}B^\theta / \mathrm{D}\lambda$, but I assume the same sort of cancellation happens there, too.

The normalisation issue is a symptom of an underlying cause. But you are correct, this is the crucial issue. Take my upvote.

Thank you very much, I got it! Yes, everything cancels and the covariant derivative along the curve in polar coordinates vanishes, as it must.

Maybe I am mistaken, but I think this depends on how you chose your basis vectors.
Given the vector in cartesian coordinates
$$B = \alpha \cdot \operatorname{\hat{x}} + \beta \cdot \operatorname{\hat{y}}$$
changing to polar coordinates using the transformation law for vectors yields
$$B^r \enspace = \enspace \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} B^x + \frac{\partial r}{\partial y} B^y \enspace = \enspace  \alpha \cos \theta + \beta \sin \theta$$
$$B^{\theta} \enspace = \enspace \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x} B^x + \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y} B^y \enspace = \enspace  - \alpha \frac{\sin \theta}{r} + \beta \frac{\cos \theta}{r} \tag{$\color{red}{!!!}$}$$
The basis vectors themselves look like
$$\operatorname{\hat{r}} \enspace = \enspace \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} \operatorname{\hat{x}} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} \operatorname{\hat{y}} \enspace = \enspace \cos \theta \operatorname{\hat{x}} + \sin \theta \operatorname{\hat{y}}$$
$$\operatorname{\hat{\theta}} \enspace = \enspace \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} \operatorname{\hat{x}} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta} \operatorname{\hat{y}} \enspace = \enspace -r \sin \theta \operatorname{\hat{x}} + r \cos \theta \operatorname{\hat{y}}$$
Within the line labelled by $(\color{red}{!!!})$ you find your $r^{-1}$ factors. You chose a basis vector of the form $\operatorname{\hat{\theta}}' := \operatorname{\hat{\theta}}/r$.

For completeness: after rearrangement, one finds.
$$\operatorname{\hat{x}} \enspace = \enspace \cos \theta \operatorname{\hat{r}} - \frac{\sin \theta}{r} \operatorname{\hat{\theta}}$$
$$\operatorname{\hat{y}} \enspace = \enspace \sin \theta \operatorname{\hat{r}} + \frac{\cos \theta}{r} \operatorname{\hat{\theta}}$$
Note that $\operatorname{\hat{x}}$ and $\operatorname{\hat{y}}$ are still unit, as the metric reads
$$g = dr^2 + r^2 \, d\theta^2$$

You got the crucial part correct, but you don't seem to know the names involved, nor why. Take my upvote nonetheless.

Thank you very much, I got it! Yes, everything cancels and the covariant derivative along the curve in polar coordinates vanishes, as it must.

You have fallen into the classic trap. Physics still loves to teach from vierbeins first, but the covariant scheme requires that you use coördinate bases. Both Octavius and Wihtedeka got it correct, but didn't give the correct name of the problem.
Vierbeins, also called tetrad formalism, your basis vectors have length = 1. But in the "correct mathematics", natural to physics, you must have covariant and contravariant quantities, and those are not in agreement with vierbeins, even though your basic physics textbooks would teach multivariable calculus in terms of them. It is only covariant momenta that are conserved quantities; the contravariant components of momenta are not conserved.
The nice mathematical trickery of differential geometry tended to be derived in terms of coördinate bases.
However, vierbeins are un-avoidable. Later, when you need to consider spinor fields, we cannot work purely in terms of the metric, because the spinor part will essentially take the square root of the metric, in which case you would have difficulties making sure that you haven't accidentally inserted a sign error. To remedy that, you apply the vierbein formalism everywhere, invariant under local Lorentz transformations. In this way, you align the spin axes and extend the validity of the GR formalisms to spinors.
Life is sad.

Ah you're right, I see what you mean now after opening Carroll again. I think your answer would be greatly improved if you added the corresponding vielbein calculation - which in this case should be fairly straight forward, since the tetrad is particular simple here?!

@Wihtedeka for lack of familiarity, I'd better not attempt. I didn't get to learn this; after years of confusion due to misunderstanding the Cartan structure equations, I only got to ask a friend if I was totally misguided about it. Didn't have the free time to relearn it from scratch.
